# WPF change cell background color based on content

Tags: wpf, cell, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I having difficulties trying to change a cell background color based on an Unbound's field (with non-simple backend structure) underneath structure.
Here is the sample "complex" structure:

```
public class TestTable
{
    public int order { get; set; }
    public TestMember t1 { get; set; }
    public TestMember t2 { get; set; }
    public TestMember t3 { get; set; }
}

public class TestMember
{
    public TestMember(String i)
    {
        value = i;
    }

    public String value { get; set; }

}
```

and this is the XAML:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="xamDataGrid1">

        <igDP:XamDataGrid.ViewSettings>
            <igDP:GridViewSettings UseNestedPanels="False"/>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.ViewSettings>

        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>
            <igDP:FieldSettings AllowRecordFiltering="true" FilterLabelIconDropDownType="MultiSelectExcelStyle" 
                                                        AllowEdit="False" AllowFixing="No" AllowSummaries="True"/>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldSettings>

        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
            <igDP:FieldLayoutSettings AutoGenerateFields="False" FilterUIType="LabelIcons" 
                                                              HeaderPrefixAreaDisplayMode="FieldChooserButton" AllowClipboardOperations="All"
                                                              CopyFieldLabelsToClipboard="True" AddNewRecordLocation="OnTopFixed"
                                                              AllowAddNew="False" HighlightAlternateRecords="False" ExpansionIndicatorDisplayMode="Never"
                                          />
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayoutSettings>
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igDP:FieldLayout Key="Layout0">
                <igDP:FieldLayout.SortedFields>
                    <igDP:FieldSortDescription  FieldName="order" Direction="Ascending"></igDP:FieldSortDescription>
                </igDP:FieldLayout.SortedFields>
                <igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
                    <igDP:Field Name="order" Label="Ordinamento" AllowGroupBy="False"  Visibility="Collapsed" FixedLocation="FixedToNearEdge"/>
                    <igDP:UnboundField BindingMode="TwoWay" BindingPath="t1.value" Name="value" AllowEdit="True" Label="Anno Recoil" AllowGroupBy="False"  FixedLocation="FixedToNearEdge"/>
                    <igDP:UnboundField BindingMode="TwoWay" BindingPath="t2.value" Name="value" AllowEdit="True" Label="APC"  FixedLocation="FixedToNearEdge"/>
                    <igDP:UnboundField BindingMode="TwoWay" BindingPath="t3.value" Name="value" Label="R1" AllowEdit="True" FixedLocation="FixedToNearEdge"/>
                </igDP:FieldLayout.Fields>
            </igDP:FieldLayout>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>

    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
```

What I'd like to get is a colored Grid the cells are black only when the root value is null, not when the leaf value is null. [image: Colored XamDataGrid]

The shown grid is the result of generating the second column rows a new TestMember with the value set to null.
I'd like them to not be colored Black and treated differently.
I've tired this converter:

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BackGroundConverter}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Value" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext"/>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="Value" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid.Resources>
```

And what happens is that the CellValuePresenter passed to the multivalue converter has no field attached when the leaf value is null so I can't find an elegant way to retrieve in which column the value is null (either by root being null or leaf being null) and create a logic to color the cell in a proper way.

Thanks in advance, leave a comment if I didn't explain properly the issue.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by declaring a multibinding converter instead of the simple one and different styles like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type igDP:CellValuePresenter}" x:Key="keyX">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BackGroundConverter}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Value" />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="DataContext"/>
                        <Binding Source="keyX"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

and inside the multivalueconverter I do my checks based on the key passed.
Obviously in the XamDataGrid you bind the style to the correspondent field, like this:

```
<igDP:UnboundField BindingMode="TwoWay" BindingPath="keyX.value" Name="value" AllowEdit="True" Label="Carica VN" FixedLocation="FixedToNearEdge">
      <igDP:Field.Settings>
            <igDP:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource keyX}" />
      </igDP:Field.Settings>
</igDP:UnboundField>
```

and in the MultiValueConverter you make a switch-case based on the third binding:

```
switch (columnValue)
{
                    case "keyX":
                        single = row.getKeyXValue();
                        colorToApply = getStandardColor(single);
                        break;
 ...
```

That's all.
Seems dirty to me, but since I've yet to find an elegant solution, this will work